# iOS parent view not resizing on rotation when modal view present

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an issue where I have a view controller that redraws its contents on rotation.  The problem is when I have modal view up and I rotate the device, the parent view doesn't get the new bounds.  How do I get the parent view to recognize the rotation?

Comment: have you overwrite method to handle your redraws on rotation? If yes could you post the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check, and possibly update, the rotation in `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`. It would be super slow if all view controllers were sent rotation updates, e.g. it can be 10 or so if you stack modal view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using auto-layout and programmatically updating constraints that depend on orientation, the solution is simple. Make sure you do all of your constraint changes in updateViewConstraints. Then in viewWillAppear and willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation, call [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints]. Works like a charm.